# Having issues with rand() and srand()

Tags: c++, switch-statement, path-finding

So i'm trying to write a pathfinder and am having some issues.

I currently have a switch() with four cases and want to choose one of them randomly.

```
do
    {
        if (checkLeft()==false && checkRight()==false && checkUp()==false && checkDown()==false)
        {
            cont = false;
        }

        int x = rand() % 4;
        srand( static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
        if (cont == true)
        {
            switch(x)
            {
                case 0:
                    checkRight();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    checkDown();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    checkUp();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    checkLeft();
                    break;
            }

        }

    } while (currentx != max && currenty != max && cont == true);
```

Because it is a 'do' loop, it seems that its not really being random? I get consistently similar results. How can I ensure that I'm getting completely random output from the switch()??

THanks!

Comment: use srand only one time in the beginning of main.

Answer (score 1):

`time(NULL)` is not required to have any resolution better than a second.  Calling it multiple times may reseed to exactly the same value multiple times unless your program runs for a significant duration.   That would explain your "consistently similar" results.   Running your code "as is" multiple times, several seconds or minutes apart, may give different results.     But, if it is run several times in quick succession, it might give the same value repeatedly, and change value slowly.

Generally speaking, call `srand()` exactly once in your program, before the first call of `rand()`.

If you're using C++11 or later, there are better quality generators available.  Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling srand () after rand() which would have already used a seed. 
Try calling srand() before rand() and it just needed to be called once. So, call it before do- while block.
Also, you may want to look at ([Random C++ Header Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/))

Answer (score 0):

Try to call srand() before do while